# Redirecting OpenVPN Server routes towards other VPNs to clients

Tags: routing, openvpn, static-routes

I have an openVPN Server that share a network in tun mode, the main network that it share is on the class : `192.40.190.0/24` .

The config file that I have on the Server is like the following :

```
local 192.40.190.8               ## ip/hostname of server
port 1194                        ## default openvpn port
proto udp
dev tun
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

#client configuration
client-to-client
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/clients
persist-key
persist-tun
float
```

Now I have attached the server to another network card (eth1) where it is connected to another network `192.168.200.0/24` where there is a another gateway(`192.168.200.15`) to others remote networks `192.168.2.0/24`, `192.168.3.0/24`, ecc ...

The VPN server that have another IP address(`192.168.200.99`) on the second NIC, can reach all the others networks because it have a route table that allow it to connect all others networks through  `192.168.200.15` gateway.

The question is : How can let the clients of the main VPN server (`192.40.190.8`, `192.168.200.99` ) connects to the `192.168.200.0/24` subnet and to the other networks behind the `192.168.200.15` gateway ?